# How to load js files correctly with nosniff header active

Tags: javascript, mime-types, content-type, mime

I have added a nosniff CONTENT_TYPE header and all my external js files loaded via `script` are causing errors

If i load resources like this:

`<script src="../resources/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>`

or like:

`<script type="application/javascript" src="../resources/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>`

Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:8080/resources/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

If I set the mime-type to "text/javascript" the error occurs when trying to execute some function, like "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function"

It is mandatory to have this security header, I can reach the js file via browser, and it was working properly before the header.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you set the X-CONTENT-TYPE to NOSNIFF on the server. If that's the case, the mime type of each resource needs to be explicitly set on the server, and match what the client expects - in your case, a JS file needs to have "application/javascript" as its content type, to be matched by the script tag.

Comment: I set up a mime-mapping specifying js mime type in web.xml and it works, thanks!